# How to generate dynamic combobox using struts1.3 action and on submit of page also getting its value?

Tags: html, jsp, struts-1

I am new to strut 1.3, need to create the dynamic combobox using struts1.3 action. I need to take the data and generate 10 comboboxes in jsp from struts1.3  action . Once the comboboxes are generated need to select the values and put select the values in action and put it into DB .

How do I do that?

Thanks,
Nirav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably something you should do:

In jsp page:

```
 <html:select property="item">
       <html:optionsCollection property="itemList" label="name" value="Item"/>
 </html:select>
```

In your form:

public class MyForm extends ActionForm{
    private LabelValueBean item = null;
    private List itemList = null;

```
public LabelValueBean getItem(){
    return item;
}
public void setItem(LabelValueBean item){
    this.item = item;
}
public List<LabelValueBean> getItemList(){
    return itemList;
}
putlic void setItemList(List<LabelValueBean> itemList){
    this.itemList = itemList;
}
```

}

In your action class populate your list:

```
public class MyAction extends Action{
    public ActionForward execute(......){
        List<LabelValueBean> newList = new ArrayList<LabelValueBean>;
            LabelValueBean lb1 = new LabelValueBean("One", "One");
            LabelValueBean lb2 = new LabelValueBean("Two", "Two");
            LabelValueBean lb3 = new LabelValueBean("Three", "Three");
            newList.add(lb1);
            newList.add(lb2);
            newList.add(lb3);

        myForm.setItemList(newList);
    }
}
```

Once the user selects an item and hits submit, you can access the selected value in your action class. The selected value is stored in your "item" property of your form class. So now you can take this value and save it in your DB.

For other comboboxes, just repeat the same thing.

Comment: For using dynamic combobox you can name the property as you are not sure how many comboboxes will be there.